# How can I get more views on a google analytics property?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using one tracking code on a website for a franchise company with 122 franchises. Each franchise has it's own subdomain, ie: city.franchisecompany.com - the main "All website data" view shows me everything, but I also need to report on each individual franchisee.

I've began this set up using a view with the filter:

```
Include Only -> Traffic to the hostname -> That contains -> city
```

However, I can only set up 25 of these. How can I get more? Or is there a better way to achieve this set up other than views?

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for stackoverflow. SO is a programming Q and A site for programming questions only. You have 1326 karma though, so I'm sure you knew that already :)

Comment: This should best be asked in Webmasters. But just to comment, the limit should be 50 views per property. You could break down the franchisees based on location and have a property for each location (ie. country or continent, etc.)

Comment: @Zerp I assumed since there was a google-analytics tag that it's safe to post here, I supposed it's only for the GA API then - but who knows, maybe the answer is that it needs to be *programmed* through the API? ;)

Comment: @nyuen strange. I only have 25.